# Gif is not Loading using Url in Glide

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, gif, android-glide

I am trying to display the gif from the link fetched from the Api but in the output, it doesn't show the gifs. It is showing the image correctly. I have used the codes already in Stack overflow but that didn't seem to work for me. Can you please help me ...
Below is the code:

ViewHolderClass

```
class GifAdapter:RecyclerView.Adapter<GifAdapter.GifViewHolder>() {
    private val items = mutableListOf<Data>()

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): GifViewHolder {
        val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gifsdisplaypattern,parent,false)
        return GifViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: GifViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val currentItem = items[position]
//        val avatar_url = currentItem.user.avatar_url
        Glide.with(holder.itemView.context).asGif().load("https://giphy.com/embed/cBnSvKscZProc").into(holder.gif)
        Log.d("Avatarurl",currentItem.embed_url)
//        Glide.with(holder.itemView.context).load(currentItem.user.profile_url).into(holder.UserImage)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        Log.d("Rohit", items.size.toString())
        return items.size
    }
    fun initData(itemsList: List<Data>){
        this.items.clear()
        this.items.addAll(itemsList)
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    class GifViewHolder(itemView:View):RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        val gif = itemView.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.tv_Image)
        val UserImage:ImageView =itemView.findViewById(R.id.usr_img)
    }

}
```

xml file

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:elevation="10dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
        >

<!--        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView-->
<!--            android:id="@+id/tv_Image"-->
<!--            android:layout_width="match_parent"-->
<!--            android:layout_height="match_parent"-->
<!--            android:scaleType="centerCrop"-->
<!--            />-->
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/tv_Image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            />
```

previously i am using currentitem.embedurl (from the data class)  in place of gif link but this too didn't worked so i put the link and found no gif is displayed so i am confused where is the problem

Output 
[image: GlideOutput]

Answer (score 1):

Try this Path, current path is looks wrong in your code.

> https://media1.giphy.com/media/cBnSvKscZProc/giphy.gif

Answer (score 0):

The answer is so silly,Acutally I was directly loading the link without the .gif extension so is the problem and now it's fine
so, just remember

```
use the appropriate extension file name
```

Before

```
Glide.with(holder.itemView.context).asGif().load("https://giphy.com/embed/cBnSvKscZProc").into(holder.gif)
```

After

```
Glide.with(holder.itemView.context).asGif().load("abc.gif").into(holder.gif)
```

Cheers :)